# Google Chrome: This setting is enforced by your administrator

Tags: google-chrome, settings, administrator

I recently updated my Chrome browser and noticed something very weird. Many fields in the Settings have been disabled. "This setting is enforced by your administrator" appears next to many fields including my saved passwords section (which I need to look up one my old passwords for a website).

Anyway, I've googled this problem on the internet many times, and I haven't been able to find a viable solution.

How do I get rid of this admin lock?

p.s. I'm connected to Chrome with my Google account.

[image: This is a screen shot from the Settings section]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found a better solution on the Chrome product forums by a user called Gary. The original thread is [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/nRJplgYPFPQ).

Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy

Open each subdirectory there and change the `*.pol` files to `*.sav`, E.g. `registry.pol` becomes `registry.sav`.

Hit <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type the following in the box and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

`reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome`

In the command promt window that opens type: Yes and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Restart Google Chrome and check whether you can change the search engine.

Comment: Deleting all the GroupPolicy folder contents when the registry is already clean solves the problem. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like it would overreach the goal. The answer from imanabidi suggests just a single .pol file.

Comment: Mr. Obvious here, but if this is a company owned computer, I would not change this setting.   Just Saying.

Comment: Thanks, I was unable to change omnibox search engine, then make it by changing `DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL` (and `DefaultSearchProviderKeyword` `DefaultSearchProviderName` optional) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

Comment: There needs to be a less aggressive way to do this, it's not good practice to delete the file on your work machine.

Answer (score 16):

Any one on windows 10 Pro , this is for you guys --

1. Open CMD in administrator mode .
2. Paste below code-

   ```
   RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers" 
   RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy" 
   gpupdate /force
   ```
3. After few seconds you will see this -

   ```
   User Policy update has completed successfully.
   Computer Policy update has completed successfully.
   ```
4. Now you can change your search engine to whatever you want.

Thank you

Comment: will this delete all grouppolicies or only chrome's settings ?

Answer (score 13):

Try to use this solution:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome

Run regedit, Delete the key, then restart Chrome.

Comment: Running Regedit then going to HKEY_Currnt_user\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome. Try to delete everything you could. Hope it helps.

Comment: how to remove it in Mac?

Comment: Well, your answer deletes every single setting set there, and *by the way* happens to unlock saving passwords. I have posted answer which contains changing the exact key we want, you might want to check it out.

Comment: I have deleted all the keys and install that again but still facing the same issue

Comment: I have a similar problem, getting the same "This setting is enforced by your administrator" message (I would even call it error message, is this a handle for malware makers or what?).

Except I can't change my omnibox search engine. I deleted all the registry entries mentioned in the solution but it didn't help. I also submitted the issue to the Chrome forum here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/nRJplgYPFPQ/1ZmUcwbqvyUJ

Comment: This isn't an acceptable solution if it only applies to one OS

Comment: Worked on my windows 10 machine. this was the best answer as it was targeted at exactly the one thing that I wanted to fix - Chrome settings were not editable

Answer (score 13):

Actually, I've got a bit more precise solution, which might be useful if you don't want to change/delete anything else.

Run `regedit`, and at the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` key you should have a `PasswordManagerEnabled` property, which probably is set to `0`.

Simply change it to `1`.

**Edit:**
I tried it on some other computer and it didn't want to work, so I rebooted my computer, made sure Chrome is closed, then changed it in the registry, and finally it worked.
So make sure Chrome is closed when you do this.

Comment: In that location, I only see `(Default)` and `DnsPrefetchingEnabled`

Comment: Can you provide me a screenshot? It would be much easier that way :) And remember I meant property, not directory.

Comment: @MohammadNajar ...and?

Comment: I did what you mentioned. Restarted my Chrome and still see the admin locks. Do I need to reboot my box for it to take effect?

Comment: @MohammadNajar Yes, it might be the problem.

Comment: unfortunately the restart still didn't resolve it :(

Comment: @MohammadNajar I had similar problem on the other computer, and resolved it - check my edited answer.

Comment: I was able to find the values under Current user HKey and not under LM, but upon changing them they keep getting reset back to zero after a reboot. I have admin rights & launched regedit with admin privileges. I also made sure Chrome is closed. any ideas?

Comment: This actually works nicely. Chrome now thinks my Org turned the setting to enabled instead of disabled. Might have to run a script for that on boot though.

Answer (score 9):

for me the default search in chrome was locked by smartsputnik.ru. and deleting all the entries in registry and also resetting and reinstalling chrome did not helped . except the below solution.

1. **Delete** related key from the registry entry-
   Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACCHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome
2. **Delete** file - C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol
3. Restart computer and the problem will be solved

[reddit source](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/360w84/how_to_solve_this_setting_is_enforced_by_your/)

Comment: I didn't have to restart the computer, just Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the setting was `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`

I deleted `Chrome` and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

(MacOS) I got this issue after getting some malware that was forcing me to use WeKnow as a search engine. To fix this on MacOs I followed [these steps](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/CFHWpKwIXqs/Lx1iakneBQAJ:)

1. Go to System Preferences, then check if there's an icon named Profiles.
2. Remove AdminPrefs profile
3. Change default search engine settings, Restart Chrome

The above partially helped (I still had WeKnow as my home page). After that I followed [these steps](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8501039):

1. Type chrome://policy/ to see the policies. You cannot change them there
2. Copy paste this into your terminal

defaults write com.google.Chrome HomepageIsNewTabPage -bool false

defaults write com.google.Chrome NewTabPageLocation -string "https://www.google.com/"

defaults write com.google.Chrome HomepageLocation -string "https://www.google.com/"

defaults delete com.google.Chrome DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL

defaults delete com.google.Chrome DefaultSearchProviderNewTabURL

defaults delete com.google.Chrome DefaultSearchProviderName

I've also ran a scan of my system with Avast antivirus that has detected some malware

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux**, you can get rid of "Managed by your organization" Chrome policies, by removing these directories (as `sudo` probably):

```
/etc/opt/chrome/policies
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
/etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended
```