# Developer Tools won't Open in Chrome "This Setting is Enforced By Your Administrator"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot open Chrome Developer Tools on my own laptop. Apparently there is this setting under `chrome://extensions` called "Developer Mode", but that little switch won't toggle. It says "This settings is Enforced by Your Administrator". Then I go to my Settings -> Update & Security -> For Developers and I toggle the "Developer Mode" in Windows.

After this it still won't toggle. I'm on Windows 10 Home Edition (just like all my other computers that use chrome)

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Chrome, restarted, etc.

[The following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997549/google-chrome-this-setting-is-enforced-by-your-administrator) regarding deleting the key did not work either.

Can someone please guide me to a solution? How is Chrome looking at my Administrator setting? Where is this setting in Windows?  (Didn't I already get to that setting? Or is there another setting in Windows elsewhere?)

[image: Image Showing Windows setting for Developer Mode On]

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907574#c4

Comment: The only solution that I found that worked was to reset the whole laptop.